# intent-filter doesn't work with ActivityTestRule in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso, android-testing

I have an application that accepts deeplink.

**Manifest.xml**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.unsigned.MagicLink"
    android:label="Some test">
    <intent-filter android:label="Test">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name=".activities.unsigned.MainScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Activity**:

```
public class MagicLink extends BusAppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            ServicesApi servicesApi = ServicesApi.init(this);
            servicesApi.setSessionId(data.getQueryParameter(HttpRemoteApi.SESSION_ID));
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

This thing works perfectly if user use it. Well I want to create a test for it now. So I write something like this:

**androidTest**:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginTest {
   @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<MainScreen> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainScreen.class);
    @Test
    public void checkSmth() { 
         clickMagicLink();
         //...
    }

    private void clickMagicLink() {
        String url = "com.myapp://login?session_id="+utils.getSessionId();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        main.launchActivity(i);
    }
}
```

But instead of starting `MagicLink` activity this thing starts `MainScreen` activity (which is `MAIN`). What do I do wrong?

P.s. I also saw something like this: `new ActivityTestRule<>(MainScreen.class,true, false);`. But with this constructor my test start, but android app doesn't (I mean emulator starts but app doesn't)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ActivityTestRule.launchActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#launchActivity(android.content.Intent)) always starts the activity being tested. You cannot use it to start any other activity. In this case, it will always start `MainActivity`. The `Intent` parameter is passed to the activity. This allows you to send extras during a test. The intent is **not** used to select which activity to launch.

Also note that the docs say

> Don't call this method directly, unless you explicitly requested not to lazily launch the Activity manually using the launchActivity flag in [`ActivityTestRule(Class, boolean, boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#ActivityTestRule(java.lang.Class<T>,%20boolean,%20boolean)).

If you want to test your `MagicLink` activity, you can use `ActivityTestRule<MagicLink>`:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MagicLinkTest {
    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<MagicLink> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainScreen.class, false, false);

    @Test
    public void testMagicLink() {
        String url = "com.myapp://login?session_id="+utils.getSessionId();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        main.launchActivity(i);

        // assertions go here
    }
}
```

You can also use `ActivityTestRule<MainScreen>` but you have to simulate the exact same actions as an actual user.

Comment: What do I do to start another activity?

Comment: @deathangel908 What is the use case of your app which you are testing?

Comment: @deathangel908 To test `MagicLink`, you should use `ActivityTestRule<MagicLink>`.

Comment: In my test case I need to perform actions in `MainScreen` activity (and others)  that will send magic link to email, users clicks on the link and opens `MagicLink` activity that logs user into system. The final assert will be `currentActivity == LoggedPage`

Comment: @deathangel908 Then your test should simulate the exact same actions as an actual user. Alternatively you can test `MagicLink` directly as I show in my edit.

Comment: Mb I should use 2 separate TestCases for it? I'm not sure if I can specify order of Tests like in `TestNg`

Comment: @deathangel908 Very likely you need at least two tests here. Each test should be complete in itself. You should **never** rely on the order tests are run.

Comment: However, you can often organize your test code so that methods can be reused for multiple tests. This is no different than making reusable classes and methods in your app proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133231/discussion-between-deathangel908-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: @deathangel908 Note that each test class should only have one `ActivityTestRule`. If multiple test classes have similar logic, you can refactor this into a third class which is used from both test classes.